Excel VBA Table to Uppercase When Leaving Cell
I have a worksheet that I had written a VBA script to change text to all UPPERCASE when leaving the cell. Since then, I had to convert the range of cells to a table column, and naturally, the script stopped working. After doing some research, I discovered that it's a different procedure when checking the value in a table. This is what I have so far, but it's not working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, as it has been quite some time since I've had to use VBA.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.ListObjects("KEYHOLDERS").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange)
    Is Nothing Then Application.EnableEvents = False Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub


Since you are working with Worksheet_Change, I recommend seeing THIS POST

What does "it's not working" mean? Is there an error? Your code is invalid. It's hard to believe that you would use this, so I'm assuming that this happened while copying the code to your post. Please edit your post and format the code correctly, adding new lines and line breaks if applicable. Maybe events remained disabled while you were testing the code. Enable them with a simple Sub EnableEvents(): Application.EnableEvents = True: End Sub, each colon (:) indicating a new line.

You were pretty close, just remember to disable events before making the required changes:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim tblColumn As ListColumn
    
    ' Define your table name here
    Set tbl = Me.ListObjects("Table1")
    
    ' Check if the changed cell is in the first column of the table
    Set tblColumn = tbl.ListColumns(1)
    If Not Intersect(Target, tblColumn.DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        ' Disable events to prevent an endless loop
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        ' Convert the cell value to uppercase
        Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
        ' Re-enable events
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub


It is very important that you include error handling when you are working with Worksheet_Change Your code will error out if the user, say enters a vlookup formula in cell 1 of  the table which returns a #N/A. In such a case Application.EnableEvents = False is not set back to true and the code will not run the next time. I have spoken about it Here

We should test that Target.Count = 1 and that KeyHolders has data.
I like to add a function to reference my listobjects in their worksheet.  In this way, it makes the code read better.  For example,  if KeyHolders was on a worksheet named "Security", I would set the worksheet wsSecurity and add Function KeyHolders() As ListObject to its code module.  I code then reference the table anywhere in the workbook like this: wsSecurity.KeyHolders.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Not Target.Value = UCase(Target) And KeyHolders.ListRows.Count > 0 Then
            If Not Intersect(Target, KeyHolders.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Target.Value = UCase(Target.Value)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Public Function KeyHolders() As ListObject
    Set KeyHolders = Me.ListObjects("KEYHOLDERS")
End Function

Note: Code adjusted as per Siddharth Rout's comments.

Before using Target.Value = UCase(Target) or Target.Count use If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub else your code may give error Out of memory for  Target.Value = UCase(Target)  and Overflow for Target.Count... I have spoken about it Here

If you are wondering how to reproduce these errors, simply select all cells in the worksheet and press the delete button on your keyboard

Thanks @SiddharthRout.   I recently saw your YouTube channel.  Great content and presentation.  I get the feeling that you are a teacher.

Thank you for your kind words. I am a programmer and Microsoft Excel/VBA/Power BI/Data Analysis Instructor.

A Worksheet Change: Convert to Uppercase

The following allows changing multiple cells.
Since writing to thousands of cells would require quite some time, it is restricted to 100 cells at a time.
It can be simplified by restricting it to a single cell as proposed by Siddharth Rout in the comments.
Although the If statement that checks if a cell contains an error should cover any surprises, I still implemented error handling to make sure events get reenabled.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     
    On Error GoTo ClearError ' start error-handling routine
     
    ' Define constants.
    Const TABLE_NAME As String = "KEYHOLDERS"
    Const COLUMN_ID As Variant = 1
    Const MAX_CELLS_COUNT As Long = 100
    
    ' Reference the target range.
    Dim trg As Range:
    Set trg = Me.ListObjects(TABLE_NAME).ListColumns(COLUMN_ID).DataBodyRange
    ' Reference the cells that were changed and are intersecting
    ' with the target range.
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(trg, Target)
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no cells of the target range were changed
    
    ' Restrict to the maximum number of cells.
    ' If e.g. thousands of cells were (accidentally) changed (via Copy/Paste),
    ' the code would take too much time ('forever').
    Dim CellsCount As Long: CellsCount = irg.Cells.CountLarge
    If CellsCount > MAX_CELLS_COUNT Then
        MsgBox CellsCount & " cells were changed. Modifying changed cells is " _
            & "restricted to a maximum of " & MAX_CELLS_COUNT & " cells!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Always disable events before writing to the same worksheet
    ' to prevent retriggering this or triggering any other events.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ' Make sure events get enabled again by using an error-handling routine.
    
    ' Convert to uppercase.
    Dim icell As Range
    For Each icell In irg.Cells
        If Not IsError(icell.Value) Then ' prevent error if cell is error
            icell.Value = UCase(icell.Value)
        End If
    Next icell
    
ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next ' defer error trapping (ignore errors)
    ' The line above prevents an endless loop if an error would occur
    ' in the continuation below.
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    On Error GoTo 0 ' enable error trapping
    Exit Sub
ClearError: ' continue error-handling routine
    MsgBox "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume ProcExit ' redirect error handling-routine
End Sub


Nicely Done. I like the way you take out time to completely comment your code :)
